# Is path.relative().indexOf('..') sufficient to guard against files outside of project root?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a utility that should only have access to files under the project folder.  Is using `path.relative` and simply checking for `..` sufficient to guard against access outside of that folder?

```
const projectFolder = '/foo/bar/baz';
const relativePath = path.relative(projectFolder, filePath);
if (relativePath.indexOf('..') >= 0) {
  throw new Error('file is not in project folder');
}
```

Comment: What happens under Windows: `path.relative('C:\\a', 'D:\\b');` ?

Comment: @shawn -- good question.  I don't have a windows VM here, can anyone on windows reading this possibly check quick?  :)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule -- In my case `filePath` and `projectFolder` are both absolute here.

Comment: Makes sense. I saw my error. Seems to be a proper check on linux based machines.

Comment: It might work, but I'd have more faith in `path.resolve(filePath).startsWith(projectFolder)`

Comment: @Bergi - thanks, can you make that an answer?  :)

Comment: I'm not confident enough to say "*Yes, it's sufficient*". There are too many traps in file path processing.